# Problem importing Vector shapes in .psb to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector-graphics, skeletal-animation

My .PSB file in photoshop has my character that is made up of vector shapes.I haven't rasterized it. When I import that .psb file to Unity , nothing shows. But if I rasterize it , it works. I want to use vector shapes without rasterizing so that I can make changes to it easily later on. Is there any way to do it ? or Am I just heading into wrong direction ?

Answer (score 1):

Unity added SVG Support some time ago:

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/10/2018-2-is-now-available/#svg

But it's a package afaik. Go to Package Manager and download it. You may have to enable Preview Packages to be able to see it in the list.

I cannot guarantee that it will work with photoshop files out of the box.

Comment: I have already tried it by downloading "vector graphics" pkg. It allows import .svg files . for that I need to export all my layers separately into svg files and import it to unity. But , if i do it that way, if I make change to actual .psb file , I'll have to repeat the whole process again.

Comment: I understand your problem. But I don't think Unity has a solution for this yet. Maybe you need a Photoshop Action to export layers, or save a rasterized copy, so you can keep your svg psb, aka have a 'non destructive' workflow...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same. Please check your "Image Mode" settings in Photoshop. It should be "8 Bits/Channel"

[image: Image Settings]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).